# Give three non-isomorphic groups of order 24, and explain why they are not isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I am not sure how to do this question, any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Well, start with: find *some* groups of order $24$. Can you name any?

Comment: (Also, are you familiar with the "direct product" of two groups $G\times H$? This question becomes easy if you are familiar with it, and hard otherwise.)

Comment: **This question is missing context or other details**: Please provide additional [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: To add on to user1729's comment, in particular are you familiar with the [Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group)?